# is it safe to rename firefox.exe?

Tags: security

OK so I am using some program that acts like a big bag of whatever you put inside it, pinned to a taskbar, so you can access tons of different programs that you put inside it (.exes) from right clicking on it, and it's working fine excepts that it tries to be smart (when it isn't), so when the program is called "firefox.exe" it automatically opens Firefox browser. So if I put Tor executable "firefox.exe" inside it will not open Tor but Firefox (same goes for Firefox Dev. Edition).

So I was wondering if I change Tor's firefox.exe to something different, will that compromise my security?

Thanks.

Comment: You need to ensure when Tor Browser launches, that it starts inside of the Tor Browser directory, not by simply launching firefox.exe.